# Использование ViewPager для перемещения между Activity

Tags: java, android

Всем привет!
Хочу сделать перемещение между панелями в приложении. Насколько я знаю во ViewPager используются Fragments. Можно ли создать на его основе что-то подобное?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет. `ViewPager` используется только c `Fragment-ами.` `ViewPager2` может использоваться просто с `View`.

`ViewPager` это `View` и он должен быть где-то размещен. Если вы не создаете Activity для него, то куда вы его положите? `Activity` в `Activity` вставлять нельзя.

Ну и главный вопрос: А чем вас не устраивают фрагменты?

Comment: Я пока что просто изучаю этот вопрос, поэтому интересуюсь что подойдёт лучше) Можно ли в Fragments добавлять списки и другие подобные элементы?

Comment: Во фрагмент можно все. Есть архитектуры где только 1 активити и 100500 фрагментов.

Comment: Тут нет лушче никаких. Если хотите ViewPager то только Fragment-ы либо кастомные View

Comment: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/174-urok-104-android-3-fragments-lifecycle.html Вот неплохой урок по фрагментам. Чтоб понять, что они могут

Comment: Спасибо! Буду изучать)

Comment: всё прописал, работает как нужно. Никак не могу понять как передать данные из Activity в Fragment. Может быть сталкивались с таким? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1161182/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-activity-%d0%b2-fragment-viewpager2
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63216163/how-to-send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-with-viewpager2