# Передача данных из Activity в Fragment ViewPager2

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь передать данные из MainActivity в один из фрагментов ViewPager2.

В MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("1", 1);
    fragment1.setArguments(bundle);
}
```

В Fragment1:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        int i = bundle.getInt("1", 0);
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "" + i);
    }
    return view;
}
```

bundle всегда null. Задача в том, чтобы при загрузке MainActivity данные отправлялись во фрагменты и при последующем их перелистывании через ViewPager2 отображались корректно.
Судя по циклу жизни Fragment1, метод onCreateView создаётся когда пользователь перелистывает на него.
Как правильно можно передавать данные в Fragment1?

UPD:

ViewPager2 инициализируется в onCreate MainActivity:

```
viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
pagerAdapter = new MainPagerAdapter(this);
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```

С помощью BottomNavigationView реализован переход между фрагментами ViewPager2:

```
bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.nav1:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav2:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav3:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Здесь же создаётся `fragment1 = new Fragment1();` и бандл.

Код адаптера:

```
public class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter
{
    public MainPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity)
    {
        super(fragmentActivity);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return new Fragment1();
            case 1:
                return new Fragment2();
            default:
                return new Fragment3();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

После загрузки MainActivity хочу передать данные в фрагменты, а не создавать их каждый раз заново. В ViewPager для этих целей используется FragmentPagerAdapter.

Есть ли аналог в ViewPager2?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111326/discussion-on-question-by-denvebber----activity--fragment-viewp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sergei Buvaka, спасибо за ответ.
Сделал так:

В MainActivity:

```
pagerAdapter = new MainPagerAdapter(this);
pagerAdapter.setData(fragment1Container);
```

В MainPagerAdapter:

```
public class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter
{
    private Fragment1Container fragment1Container;
    private Fragment2Container fragment2Container;

    public void setData(Fragment1Container container)
    {
        fragment1Container = container;
    }

    public void setData(Fragment2Container container)
    {
        fragment2Container = container;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                Gson gson = new Gson();

                bundle.putString("fragment1Container", gson.toJson(fragment1Container));
                fragment1.setArguments(bundle);

                return fragment1;
            case 1:...
```

В Fragment1:

```
private Fragment1Container fragment1Container;

if (bundle != null)
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = bundle.getString("fragment1Container");
    Type entityType = new TypeToken<Fragment1Container>(){}.getType();
    fragment1Container = gson.fromJson(jsonString , entityType );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько путей:

- Вы можете в вашей `Activity` подготовить список фрагментов с бандлами и всеми данными и в ваш `MainPagerAdapter` передать этот список. Соответственно в методе

  ```
  public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
  }
  ```

  вы не создаете новый фрагмент как у вас в коде, а просто берете его экземпляр из списка `fragments` который вы предварительно создали в `Activity` и положили (например через конструктор или метод set-er).
- Второй путь вы можете создавать готовый список нужных вам аргументов в `Activity` и так же класть в ваш адаптер, и класть эти аргументы при создании фрагментов все в том же методе `createFragment`. Хотя по сути это те же яйца только в профиль.
- В целом можно создать в ваших фрагментах какой-то метод кастомный типа `setArguments(String anyString);` и аналогичный метод в адаптере

  ```
  void setArguments(String anyString, Int fragmentPos) {
      fragments.get(fragmentPos).setArguments(anyString);
  }
  ```

  и передавать туда что-либо динамически. Если ваши фрагменты будут различны, то вам придется еще обрабатывать логику для каждого фрагмента, но мне суть остается той же.
- Еще вариант это сделать общую сущность которая будет шариться между `Activity` и всеми фрагментами `ViewPager-а` - **Singleton** или `Presenter`/`ViewModel` и шарить нужные данные через эту сущность. Для динамического управления фрагментами я бы использовал именно этот способ.